# Horário de Verão em Perl e PHP no CentOS

Tags: centos, perl, timezone

Estou com um problema de horário de verão no CentOS 7.8. O pacote tzdata já foi atulizado para não mudar o horário (pacote padrão do sistema), mas as funções em Perl e PHP continuam reportando 1h a mais.

```
# yum list tzdata
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
tzdata.noarch                                          2020d-2.el7                                           @centos7-x86_64-updates

# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 37 Set 25  2019 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo
```

Diferença nas datas:

```
# date
Seg Nov 16 11:38:52 -03 2020

# perl -MDateTime -le'print DateTime->now->set_time_zone("UTC")'
2020-11-16T14:38:52

# perl -MDateTime -le'print DateTime->now->set_time_zone("America/Sao_Paulo")'
2020-11-16T12:38:52
```

Atualizei o sistema, reiniciei, mas não consigo ver o horário correto no timezone America/Sao_Paulo nos scripts e aplicações web em PHP.

Onde estaria a definição errado do timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Sei que passou um bom tempo, mas pode servir pra outra pessoa. O timezone do PHP fica no arquivo PHP.ini. Você precisa editá-lo e encontrar a seguinte área:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

Alterando o date.timezone para "America/Sao_Paulo" deve resolver o problema (por padrão vem UTC).